# Check if a URL file exists in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to check if a file to download exists or not.

I searched for a specific command but I have not found it so I thought to use the `DownloadTemporaryFileSize` command that throws an exception if something goes wrong.

Suppose that the file doesn't exist, I expected that the catching the exception error it will be hidden, but why it is not?

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  try 
    FileSizeRetrieved := DownloadTemporaryFileSize('https://example.com/my_picture.jpg')
  except
    if....
      //do something
      //SuppressibleMsgBox(AddPeriod(GetExceptionMessage), mbCriticalError, MB_OK, IDOK);
    end;
  end;
    
  MsgBox(IntToStr(FileSizeRetrieved), mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what you are actually doing, as the code you have posted won't even compile. The following compilable version of your code proves that in general your approach is correct. The code won't show any message box, even if the download does not exist.

```pascal
function DownloadExists(Url: string): Boolean;
var
  Size: Int64;
begin
  try 
    Size := DownloadTemporaryFileSize(Url)
    Log(Format('Size of %s download is %d', [Url, Size]));
    Result := True;
  except
    Log(Format('Download %s does not exist: %s', [Url, GetExceptionMessage]));
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Note that you still get an exception, when *debugging the code in IDE*. But it won't happen when executed normally.